# hibernate+spring application. add logic before using database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, orm

I write hibernate+spring application.

After application launch (But before first using) I want to check database state.

if state is good - skip logic

if state is bad - execute logic that will make state is good.

Can you guess best practies for this problem?

**UPDATE**  for *Debojit Saikia*

if I write this code:

```
@Configuration
public class UiConfig {

    @Bean
    public AppListener getMyListener(){
        AppListener appListener = new AppListener();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" appListener method ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        return appListener;
    }
}

class AppListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(" hello AppListener");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

I see next log in console:

```
21.10.2013 18:46:05 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;%ANT_HOME%/bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5\\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-ant-1.9.0/bin;.
21.10.2013 18:46:06 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ui' did not find a matching property.
21.10.2013 18:46:06 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
21.10.2013 18:46:06 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
21.10.2013 18:46:06 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 762 ms
...
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/security_config.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@77be91c8: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,candidateDao,eventDaoImpl,eventStatusDao,eventTypeDao,noteDao,skillDao,userDao,vacancyDao,candidateService,eventService,utilService,vacancyService,baseMenuController,candidateMenuController,provider,eventMenuController,homeController,uiConfig,vacancyMenuController,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,dataSource,sessionFactory,entryPoint,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,messageSource,getMyListener]; root of factory hierarchy


 appListener method 




 hello AppListener


INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4544 ms
21.10.2013 18:46:21 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Mon Oct 21 18:46:21 MSK 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
...
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/addVacancy],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.VacancyMenuController.addVacancy(com.epam.hhsystem.model.vacancy.Vacancy,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'


 appListener method 




 hello AppListener




 hello AppListener


INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 770 ms
21.10.2013 18:46:22 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
21.10.2013 18:46:22 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
21.10.2013 18:46:22 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 16053 ms
```

This listener invokes more 1 time after I run my tomcat.

I want that it invoke only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use(assuming you in servlet context environment) listeners, I would create a listener by implementing `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` and put them as last listener. It will be called as last listener(depends on the server too, check the doc of the server). In the listener I would make sure state is good. The good thing is about this, It is being called before any request to server. Web server/web container guarantees this for you.

Example:

```
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
      public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce){
          //do your work here
      }     
}
```

in web xml:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.my.MyContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: in web.xml I need to write <listener>
    *<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>*  where I must to write my logic?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement InitializingBean or use @PostConstruct on one of your beans. this will execute code in annotated (implemented) method when bean is created. So do your logic there and don't forget about transactions. Also you may be interested in @DependsOn annotaion (or depends-on property)

Comment: Could you please provide more details? maybe example

Comment: Just create class annotated with '@Service' or '@Component'
with method annotated with '@PostConstruct'
Method will be called once on your application start-up

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ApplicationListener` to listen to `ContextRefreshedEvent` event, so that you can poll your database once all beans are loaded, post-processor beans are detected and activated, and the `ApplicationContext` object is ready for use:

```
public class AppListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        // CODE TO CHECK DB STATE
    }

}
```

and you need to make an entry for this listener in your context config file:

```
<bean id="appListener" class="x.y.z.AppListener" />
```

With this the bean will be notified when the application context is initialized or refreshed.

**EDIT:**

The `listener` is getting invoked twice because there may be two different context initialization events. Even though you haven't specified a `contextConfigLocation` for your DispatcherServlet it still creates a child context and the second refreshed event is for that context. You can use

```
event.getApplicationContext()
```

to find out for which context the listener is executed.